# Is there any IDE to navigate multiple php and css files?

Tags: php, css

I downloaded the [SMThemes](http://smthemes.com/demo/healthcare).It is kind of similar to wordPress.

However, as I copied the files the `index.php` does not execute properly

```
<?php 
    global $SMTheme;

    get_header(); 

    get_template_part('theloop');

    get_template_part('navigation');

    get_footer();

?>
```

I cannot find where the `get_header` is defined.

There is no such a function in the `functions.php`, and there is no `includes` folder.

Comment: Pleas download an evaluation copy of PHPStorm, load the source as a project and use the IDE to automatically find the definition of get_header().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, [SMThemes](http://smthemes.com/demo/healthcare) is a **WordPress** theme. See the comment at the end of the link.

`get_header()` is defined in the **WordPress** core itself and not in the theme files, due this you weren't able to find it there.

You can find its definition at `wp-installation-root/wp-includes/general-template.php` file, Line **24**, and its definition is:

```
/**
 * Load header template.
 *
 * Includes the header template for a theme or if a name is specified then a
 * specialised header will be included.
 *
 * For the parameter, if the file is called "header-special.php" then specify
 * "special".
 *
 * @uses locate_template()
 * @since 1.5.0
 * @uses do_action() Calls 'get_header' action.
 *
 * @param string $name The name of the specialised header.
 */
function get_header( $name = null ) {
    do_action( 'get_header', $name );

    $templates = array();
    $name = (string) $name;
    if ( '' !== $name )
        $templates[] = "header-{$name}.php";

    $templates[] = 'header.php';

    // Backward compat code will be removed in a future release
    if ('' == locate_template($templates, true))
        load_template( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/theme-compat/header.php');
}
```

As of your real question, you can follow @SteAp suggestion and give [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) a try, its very nice indeed and this kind of issues you will solve them easily (I don't work for **JetBrains**).